# Today's world record on the Betti numbers of Calabi-Yau three-folds.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, calabi-yau, reference-request

What are largest betti numbers $b_2$ and $b_3$ of three-dimensional Calabi-Yau manifolds that are discovered for today?

Is there some nice reference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since mirror symmetry exchanges the Hodge numbers $h^{1,1} = b_2$ and $h^{2,1} = \frac{1}{2}(b_3 - 1)$, it is perhaps more natural (and of course equivalent) to discuss these.  The record-holders all come from the [list of hypersurfaces](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002240) in toric fourfolds, constructed by Kreuzer and Skarke.  The largest value of 
$h^{1,1}$ is $491$, and the same for $h^{2,1}$.  These two manifolds (which are mirror) also hold the record for largest $h^{1,1} + h^{2,1}$, which is 502.  There is a third manifold which shares this record; its Hodge numbers are $(251,251)$, and it is also in the Kreuzer-Skarke list.

See [this recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1205.0952) and [this one](http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1207.4792) for nice plots and a discussion of these Calabi-Yau threefolds and others with large Hodge numbers.

Comment: Rhys, thanks a lot for the answer and for the links to two articles!