# What is the meaning of $(h^{11},h^{21})\to (h^{11}-240,h^{21}+240)$ in Calabi-Yau threefolds?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, hodge-theory, mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau

By browsing through the Hodge data of known Calabi-Yau threefolds, I stumbled upon an observation that frequently enough a pair of Hodge numbers $(h^{11},h^{21})$ comes together with the pair  $ (h^{11}-240,h^{21}+240)$. This shift, together with mirror symmetry accounts for a certain symmetry in the top portion of the Kreuzer-Skarke plot.

Has anyone observed this shift before?

Is there an empirical explanation for this shift?
Is there any relation to the roots of $E_8$?

Are there other similar but smaller shifts?

Comment: A very interesting observation.

Comment: In the sactter plot, do the two parabola-like upper curves match up if one is translated to the other?

Comment: I believe so. I zoomed in on the picture near the vertex of the parabola and it was completely symmetric. Also notice that the top points are $(11,491),(251,251),(491,11)$ which exhibits the same shift twice.

Comment: Certainly very intriguing. I didn't realise that the curve was symmetric.

Comment: By the way, one thought occurs to me prompted by your mention of $E_8$. The CY with Hodge numbers 11 and 491 is easily described as a general elliptic fibration over the Hirzebruch surface $F_12$. If memory serves me right, this fibration has a curve of type $II^*$ fibres over the section with self-intersection $-12$. Of course this fibre has an extended $E_8$ Dynkin diagram.

Comment: Look at this image: http://benjaminjurke.net/dynamic/cyexp/cy.svg?h11=17&h21=257&depth=120
There is almost a perfect symmetry in the top ranges, as if there was some sort of mechanism to get the new Hodge pair if the original numbers are large enough.

Comment: By the way, the curves definitely resemble hyperbolas rather than parabolas, but I have not guessed the hypothetical equation just yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the mathoverflow answer
[Today's world record on the Betti numbers of Calabi-Yau three-folds.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110535/todays-world-record-on-the-betti-numbers-of-calabi-yau-three-folds/110547#110547),
the paper http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:1207.4792 is cited. In this paper, the shift of Hodge numbers by (-240,240) is mentionned and the symmetry is explained, at least for the Calabi-Yau
threefolds obtained from reflexive polytopes by the Batyrev's construction. E_8 plays indeed an important role (via Calabi-Yau which are K3 fibrations).

EDIT: a video conference of P.Candelas on this paper : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4996MUz25vg

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense to me at least at the combinatorial level.